# multiple slidershows on one site?

Tags: javascript, html

javascript newbee here :|

I created a slidershow, but i need to add 4 more slidershows on my website, if i add more slidershows only the first slidershow works, the other stand still :/

can someone explain me, what i need to change, to get multiple slidershows on my website?

here's my java script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image1=new Image()
        image1.src="bilder/tfb_g/slide1.jpg"
        var image2=new Image()
        image2.src="bilder/tfb_g/slide2.jpg"
        var image3=new Image()
        image3.src="bilder/tfb_g/slide3.jpg"
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1
        function slideit (){
        document.images.slide.src=eval('image'+step+'.src')
        if(step<3)
        step++
        else
        step=1
        setTimeout('slideit ()',3000)
        }
        slideit()
    </script>
```

and here is the picture in my body:

```
<img class="small" src="./bilder/tfb_g/slide.jpg" name="slide">
```

i'm a bit helpless xP

Comment: Are all sliders having the same images? You probably need to write it quite different to how you have currently written it, if you need to reuse it. You need to create  a slider function, to which you pass in the required slider handler elements, and image sources for the slider, and separate the slider logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a class:

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "bilder/tfb_g/slide1.jpg";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "bilder/tfb_g/slide2.jpg";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "bilder/tfb_g/slide3.jpg";


SlideShow = function (ele) {
    this.step = 1;
    this.element = ele;

    this.Move = function () {
        this.element.src = eval('image' + this.step + '.src');
        if (this.step < 3) this.step++;
        else this.step = 1;

        setTimeout(this.Move(), 3000);
    };
};
```

and for the HTML

```
<img class="small" src="./bilder/tfb_g/slide.jpg" onload="slideshow1 = new SlideShow(this); slideshow1.Move();">
```

but make sure for each element, you rename the inline javascript variables. 
EX:

```
slideshow2 = new SlideShow(this); slideshow2.Move();
slideshow3 = new SlideShow(this); slideshow3.Move();
slideshow65 = new SlideShow(this); slideshow65.Move();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxbrpgj/

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, it works fine! :D - but its extremely laggy, like your jsfiddle - i get an "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in google chrome, why i get this error?

Comment: try updating the setTimeout to look like this: setTimeout(this.Move, 3000);

Comment: In my jsfiddle, it elimates the error and the lag, but in turn creates an error in their console. If it doesn't work, Let me know.